# Delphi soap client - no response from server

Tags: delphi, soap, webservice-client

My application consumes some web service.
Segment of calling is below.

```
try
  intf := getInterface(urlString);
  request := TransaccionWS1.VentaDispositivoConvenioWSINTO.Create;
  // here request field are initiated
  //
  //
  AddToLogFile(format('Transaction Send: tid=%s authid=%s prod=%s',
    [request.idExterno, request.nroReserva, elem.codProducto]), log_debug);

  rs := intf.ventaDispositivoConvenio(request);
  AddToLogFile(format('Transaction Recv: OK=%d result=%s auth_result=%s ' +
              'descr=%s ticketnr=%s amount=%s text=%s',
    [ord(rs.OK), rs.codigoRetorno, rs.codigoAutorizacion, rs.descripcionRetorno,
     rs.nroTicket, rs.importeTicket, rs.textoLegal]), log_debug);
except
  on e:exception do begin
    AddToLogFile(format('**** Transaction: %s', [e.message]), log_exceptions);
    raise;
  end
end;
```

In general it is working ok
But sometimes i have a problem
I can see in log 'Transaction Send' but cannot see no 'Transaction Recv' and no exception.

Another thing i cannot explain, sometimes i see in log

03/01/2014 14:32:35.453   Transaction Send: tid=266996 authid=0000001958472 prod=86

03/01/2014 14:36:09.046   **** Transaction: The connection with the server was reset

Here exception raised after 4 minutes, while client use default timeouts values 30 seconds

May be someone has direction where to search?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that your code is wrong, but maybe it's environmental?  Consume the WSDL with SoapUI and run some tests to see if the webservice is stable and reachable.

Comment: it runs 24*7, and problem happens one time in a month.